# CodeTaskFactory" could not be found in the assembly"

Tags: macos, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017, nopcommerce

I'm new in Dot net after I cloned some project from GitHub, I try to run then got below error.

OS: Mac 10.12.6 (16G29)
Tool version: Visual stuido 2017
SDK: 2

```
/Volumes/Users/Administrator/Documents/My Web Sites/nopCommerce-develop
/nopCommerce-develop/src/Build/ClearPluginAssemblies.proj(5,5): Error MSB4174:
 The task factory "CodeTaskFactory" could not be found in the assembly "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.2.0/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Micro
soft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll". (MSB4174) (Nop.Web)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the previous answer:

nopCommerce 4.0 has developed with .NET core, but still its targeting to .NET Framework 4.6 and not .NET Core. So you cannot run nopCommerce 4.0 to MAC or Linux.

Still if you would like to run it to cross platform, you can change the targeted framework to .NET Core and solve the errors may you face.

Comment: If do that i will face alot of problem and can not solve because it need to be change more